# concatenate two strings

Tags: android, string

Let's say I have a string obtained from a cursor,this way:

```
String name = cursor.getString(numcol);
```

and another String like this one:

```
String dest=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_DESTINATIE));
```

If finally I wanna obtain a String from the two of them,something like:

```
name - dest
```

Let say if name=Malmo and dest=Copenhagen

How could I finally obtain Malmo-Copenhagen???

Because android won't let me write :

```
name"-"dest
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way in my eyes is to use the `concat()` method provided by the `String` class itself.

The useage would, in your case, look like this:

```
String myConcatedString = cursor.getString(numcol).concat('-').
       concat(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_DESTINATIE)));
```

Answer (score 51):

You need to use the string concatenation operator `+`

```
String both = name + "-" + dest;
```

Comment: or use the String class method concat(). For example, name.concat("-").concat(dest)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Jasonw - Calling `concat` twice is likely to be less efficient, as it creates an extra String object compared to how the compiler translates the in-line expression that Jon suggested. Also, Jon's solution is less typing. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use concatenation operator and instead of declaring two variables only use one variable

```
String finalString =  cursor.getString(numcol) + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(db.KEY_DESTINATIE));
```

Comment: Btw "+" is the concatenation operator, and in case if your one of the value is not String then you need to cast it to String.

Comment: You'd only need to convert to a string if *both* values were non-strings.