# TextView showing R.java Resource IDs

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I'm trying to display more than one thing in a single textview of my dialog using a `+` in between BUT when i do this it shows the resource ID of the 1st string and then it shows the 2nd string normally. Here's an excerpt of my code.

```
TextView text = (TextView)
dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
text.setText(R.string.aboutDialog + strVersion);
```

`strVersion` is a string variable that gets initialized before this. It shows the VersionName in the dialog.

So for example when the dialog is shown, instead of showing the contents of BOTH `R.string.aboutDialog` and `strVersion` it shows the R.java resource ID of `R.string.aboutDialog`.

Example of what it looks like:

```
    [About This App]
    2131034115 
    Version: 1.5-debug
      [OK]
```

The 2131034115 seems to be the resource ID of the `R.string.aboutDialog`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you post xml for aboutDialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
text.setText(R.string.aboutDialog + strVersion);
```

to

```
text.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.aboutDialog) + strVersion);
```

Comment: That's the right way to do. R.string.aboutDialog it's an int (the id of the resource) so you were concatenating a int with a string and not the relative resource with the string :)

Comment: This did it! Thanks! I knew it was an easy fix!! and thanks @StErMi for explaining. Makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the strings first into a different string - and then setting it in setText().

[concatenate two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244307/concatenate-two-strings)

Comment: Looks like this might have worked as well. Thanks for the answer. Upvoted.